# React Native wait for AsyncStorage to get value

Tags: async-await, react-native, asyncstorage

Its a common problem, React Native trying to render before the values have been fetched from AsyncStorage. I've seen solutions for this in several places but for some reason it just doesn't work at all for me. Maybe its because I'm using React Native 25.1? It just gets stuck on 'Loading...' indefinitely. If I run a console log on render to show isLoading (without the `if` method) it returns `false` and then `true` so theoretically it should be working. But with the `if` method enabled its stuck on 'Loading' forever and also the log only returns false.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';

  class MainPage extends Component {
   constructor(props: Object): void {
   super();
   this.state = {
     isLoading: false,
   };
 }

  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((token) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
    }
    // this is the content you want to show after the promise has resolved
    return <View/>;
  }

});
```

Comment: Did you try putting the code into `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 10):

Hey try this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';

class MainPage extends Component {

   constructor(props: Object): void {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         isLoading: false,
       };
   }

  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((token) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
    }
    // this is the content you want to show after the promise has resolved
    return <View/>;
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications...

Comment: Ok you seem to have just corrected my typo ie leaving the "var component = React.createClass({" in by accident. Obviously that isn't the issue or it would instantly throw an error, it wouldn't show the 'Loading' screen in the first place, never mind for too long.

Unless there's something else in your code but as far as I can see its identical apart from removing the typo?

Comment: Hey.. same code and react-native 0.25.1 is working for me here in my system.

Comment: i am getting this Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. @jickson